# How would I go about creating a Java webpage search tool

Tags: java, search, html

I want to search webpages with a Java tool that can tell me if it finds a string(s) I've asked it to look for. The thing is, the webpages I want to search have text in hover boxes that needs searching too.

I want it to automatically search pages (they have page numbers in the url) and give me a message or something that tells me the location of where the string(s) was/were found, and continue searching.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), a browser automator.

Comment: Selenium is for testing that interface functions work, not for searching pages.

Comment: @Catfish A screwdriver may be for driving screws, but that doesn't mean you can't also use it as a pry bar if it's what you have lying around. I've used Selenium for web scraping, and while it may not be the most elegant solution, it provided EXTREMELY fast prototyping.

It also comes with a Firefox plugin that allows you to record macros. However, I don't know if you can translate those macros into Chrome.

Comment: For sure ... Selenium API is in Java and damn efficient. It works with chrome and many other browsers.

Comment: I've not used Selenium more than for interface testing so it looks like i stand corrected.

Comment: @Catfish The problem is not to search data into one web page, but it is for crawling into multiple pages and grab data that can be rendered by Javascript for example (=hover boxes). A web automator is the only way to do this efficiently, and Selenium is just the best tool. Selenium can be easilly embedded into a Java software.

Comment: @Toilal Is it difficult to set up? I fear I may need assistance in the matter

Comment: If you are using maven, check out this page to configure you project. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp 
Then the API is really easy to use, it will simulate a browser from Java and you can navigate as a User by using CSS ou XPath selectors. If you are fluent with CSS ou XPath, it'll be easy ...
See tutorial on Google Code : https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) may get you close to what you're looking for. It's just a search tool, but it might be customizable to your extent. Otherwise you'll probably have to write something like that.